# When watching the past approved/rejected edits, allow the "Next" button to navigate through them

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, recent-activity, review

If I visit the page showing the history of the approved/rejected suggested-edits, I can click on the "Approve"/"Reject" link to see how the suggested edit changed the post. The page I see show a "Next" button, which just takes me to the next suggested edit to review, or to a page saying, "There are no items for you to review."

[image: screenshot]

It would be helpful if that button would take me to the next approved/rejected edit. In that way, users who want to learn from the past approved/rejected edits can navigate them without returning to the history page, remembering which suggested edit they reviewed, and clicking to see the next suggested edit, remembering not to click on the post link, which takes you to the post.